# Compiling mod_wsgi on 64 bit linux containing 32-bit python interpreter

Tags: python, 32bit-64bit, mod-wsgi

I am facing problems when i am trying to compile mod_wsgi on my linux system(64-bit) containing 32-bit python interpreter.

When i run:

```
./configure --with-apxs=/x/home16/eveljee/httpd-2.4.4/bin/apxs --with-python=/x/home16/eveljee/python32/bin/python2.6
```

I get

```
checking Apache version... 2.4.4
/x/home16/eveljee/python32/bin/python2.6: error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.6.so.1.0: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
/x/home16/eveljee/python32/bin/python2.6: error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.6.so.1.0: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
/x/home16/eveljee/python32/bin/python2.6: error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.6.so.1.0: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
/x/home16/eveljee/python32/bin/python2.6: error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.6.so.1.0: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
/x/home16/eveljee/python32/bin/python2.6: error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.6.so.1.0: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
/x/home16/eveljee/python32/bin/python2.6: error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.6.so.1.0: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
/x/home16/eveljee/python32/bin/python2.6: error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.6.so.1.0: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
/x/home16/eveljee/python32/bin/python2.6: error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.6.so.1.0: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
/x/home16/eveljee/python32/bin/python2.6: error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.6.so.1.0: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
/x/home16/eveljee/python32/bin/python2.6: error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.6.so.1.0: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
```

I realize that if i use a 64-bit python interpreter, the issue will be resolved. However for a certain reasons i can't change my python interpreter.Is there any other solution to this problem?
Also please note that i don't have root access on the system

Answer (score 0):

Loading 32-bit libraries in 64-bit linux is not supported, mainly because of problems with pointers. 64-bit machines can address above 4GB, which simply doesn't fit into a 32-bit pointer.

Note that it's not *impossible* (windows does it), but it's complicated.

Why don't you install a 64-bit Python in your home directory? It won't interfere with the system's default Python.

Comment: i have tried doing installing a 64-bit Python interpreter and mod_wsgi got successfully installed. However i am still getting an internal server error(500). When i checked the logs, it says it gives me a import error:  from cStringIO import StringIO as _StringIO
[Mon Apr 15 23:13:09.251774 2013] [:error] [pid 8724:tid 1109965120] [client 10.239.37.53:62869] ImportError: /x/opt/pp/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/cStringIO.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32

Comment: You cant just point mod_wsgi at a different Python installation using PYTHONPATH. It has to be compiled for the specific version and bit variant.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton: I've removed my comment since it is incorrect. And I see that Ejaz is already pointing the configure process to the python instance.